# Assembly is not rewritten by ccrewriter even though Runtime Checking = true

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-contracts

I have a project. In this project I'm using code contracts for .NET. I set Runtime Checking = true. [image]. But at runtime I have a ContractException:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractException' in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: An assembly (probably "Common") must be
>   rewritten using the code contracts binary rewriter (CCRewrite) because
>   it is calling Contract.Ensures and the CONTRACTS_FULL symbol is
>   defined.  Remove any explicit definitions of the CONTRACTS_FULL symbol
>   from your project and rebuild.  CCRewrite can be downloaded from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=169180.
>
> After the rewriter is installed, it can be enabled in Visual Studio
>   from the project's Properties page on the Code Contracts pane.  Ensure
>   that "Perform Runtime Contract Checking" is enabled, which will define
>   CONTRACTS_FULL
>   The cause of the exception is not that condition doesn't fulfill, but that the assembly is not rewritten. Ccrewriter is installed, I don't have troubles with other projects.

The code where it happens:

```
Contract.Ensures(_instance != null && _instance._authData != null);
```

This code is not rewritten so it executes at the start of the procedure.

I know there is a workaround to just use postbuild event to execute ccrewrite, but I'd like to avoid it.

What can be the reason for such a behavior? How can I check if ccrewrite was even invoked? I don't see any information in my build output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in CC. I found a weird workaroud:

Csproj file of my project was edited by hands before, so it had section with signAssebly tag and codecontracts settings:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
  <CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking>True</CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking>
  <CodeContractsRuntimeOnlyPublicSurface>False</CodeContractsRuntimeOnlyPublicSurface>
  <CodeContractsRuntimeSkipQuantifiers>False</CodeContractsRuntimeSkipQuantifiers>

  ....

  <CodeContractsRuntimeCheckingLevel>Full</CodeContractsRuntimeCheckingLevel>
  <CodeContractsReferenceAssembly>DoNotBuild</CodeContractsReferenceAssembly>
  <CodeContractsAnalysisWarningLevel>3</CodeContractsAnalysisWarningLevel>
  <RunCodeAnalysis>false</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So I moved CodeContracts setting to the part where it is usually stored;

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  <CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking>True</CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking>
  <CodeContractsRuntimeOnlyPublicSurface>False</CodeContractsRuntimeOnlyPublicSurface>
  <CodeContractsRuntimeThrowOnFailure>True</CodeContractsRuntimeThrowOnFailure>

  ....

  <CodeContractsReferenceAssembly>%28none%29</CodeContractsReferenceAssembly>
  <CodeContractsAnalysisWarningLevel>0</CodeContractsAnalysisWarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup
```

And now it works. I thought there is no big differnce where to put sections, and it only matters for build targets.

If someone can explain, why it happens, I will reaccept the answer.